# In Ubuntu SDK, I can't test apps on my Nexus phone (Server Rejected Key)

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, nexus-4, webapp-development

I just made my first webapp for Ubuntu Touch with the Ubuntu SDK. If I test using deploy locally, it works fine. If I test on my device, it returns me :

"-1: error: Could not connect to host: Server rejected key.
Is the device connected and set up for network access?"

I have network access (I tested Wi-Fi and 3G, no difference), device is well connected, seen ready by the SDK, developer mode enabled...

Do you have any idea what it's coming from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've the explanation. This is an actual bug described there https://bugs.launchpad.net/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu/+bug/1365952. I workarouned it with indication in comment #3